# releasing a retained property thats been autoreleased?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, retain

Hey all. Ive got a headache trying to get my head around this. I have a retained property of type NSNumber. When I use this property I instantiate it with an autoreleased NSNumber. When dealloc is called I then get bad access telling me that Im releasing something that has already been released. Heres some code.

```
@interface RadarAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {    
 }
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *latitude;
@end

@implementation RadarAnnotation

@synthesize latitude;

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
 {
coordinate.latitude = [self.latitude doubleValue];
return coordinate;
}

 -(void) dealloc {
[super dealloc];
[latitude release];//error is here when mapViewController is popped off stack.
}
```

Here is how I instantiate the property in my mapViewController :

```
poi.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:map.centerCoordinate.latitude];
```

What am I doing wrong? Many thanks. Jules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling [super dealloc] at the end of the dealloc method.

Comment: Because NSObject's implementation of -dealloc handles actually deallocating things. If you override it and don't call the superclass's implementation, nothing is ever deallocated. As a result, all dealloc methods must call [super dealloc] at the end.